# GIT, exibição dos branchs na arvore do bitbucket

Tags: git

Olá!
Estou a dias pesquisando e não encontrei nenhuma informação que me ajuda-se.

meu problema é com a exibição da arvore dos commits e branchs no bitbucket.

eu crio um branch a partir do master `git checkout -b develop` vou fazendo os commits e depois volto para o master e faço um merge do develop.

eu gostaria que ficasse com um gráfico igual ao exemplo abaixo:

```
* merged from develop
|\
| * - commit 5
| * - commit 4
| * - commit 3
| * - commit 2
| * - commit 1
|/
* branch master
```

[image: como eu gostaria]

porem só fica uma linha reta

```
*
* - commit 5
* - commit 4
* - commit 3
* - commit 2
* - commit 1
* - branch master
```

[image: como fica]

a princípio só consigo fazer como eu gostaria pelo pull request do próprio bitbucket, mas gostaria de fazer por linha de comando no git-bash.

Obrigado desde já!

Comment: vc está trabalhando diretamente na master, por isso está numa linha reta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Através de alguns links daqui em inglês encontrei [uma pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850369/why-does-git-fast-forward-merges-by-default/2850413#2850413) no qual descobri o nome da função do git que estava procurando, se chama "FAST-FORWARD" deixei como padrão desabilitado no git `git config --global merge.ff false`

Obrigado pela colaboração de todos

Answer (score 6):

Basta você fazer o merge sem *fast-foward*. Você pode fazer isso com o seguinte comando: `git merge develop --no-ff`. o `--no-ff` garante que ao fazer o merge, será gerado um novo commit.

Caso você queira visualizar a árvore na linha de comando, da mesma forma que você visualiza no Bitbucket, basta executar esse comando:

```
git log --graph --all --oneline --decorate
```

- `--graph` mostra em forma de gráfico
- `--all` indica que será mostrado todas as `branch`s
- `--oneline` define que será mostrado apenas a primeira linha do commit e com o hash do commit abreviado
- `--decorate` garante que os nomes dos `branch`s irão aparecer

Para finalizar, você ainda pode criar um `alias` para facilitar futuras digitações do comando com `git config --global alias.graph "log --graph --all --oneline --decorate"` e depois só executar o `alias` com `git graph`.

O resultado do comando é mais ou menos o que aparece na imagem abaixo:

[image: resultado do git log]

Answer (score 2):

Isso é como você trabalha.

No caso, quando você trabalha na mesma branch (master), ele segue uma linha corrente.

Para trabalhar em paralelo, você tem que criar uma branch nova a partir da master.

> seuprojeto (master): `git checkout -bPRO-01-nome-branch-mudanca`.

E então começar a trabalhar no ticket. Depois, que terminar, faz o commit das mudanças:

> seuprojeto (PRO-01-nome-branch-mudanca): `git commit -am"PRO-01 mudanças feitas xyz #resolve"`.

Depois envie a branch para o bitbucket:

> seuprojeto (PRO-01-nome-branch-mudanca): `git push origin PRO-01-nome-branch-mudanca`

Em seguida, dê checkout na master, staging ou deploy (depende de como trabalha):

> seuprojeto (PRO-01-nome-branch-mudanca): `git checkout master`

Traga para o seu local as atualizações de outros:

> seuprojeto (master):`git pull origin master`

Mescle as alterações com a master:

> seuprojeto (master):`git merge PRO-01-nome-branch-mudanca`

Resolva os conflitos (se hover):

> `git diff [branch_1]:file-exemplo [branch_2]:file-exemplo`

Após resolver os conflitos (se houver) faça o commit da resolução.

> seuprojeto (master):`git commit -am"PRO-01 conflitos resolvidos"`

E finalmente, dê o push para o master:

> seuprojeto (master):`git push origin master`

**PS:** veja se no bitbucket, vc está listando todos os commits no filtro:

https://bitbucket.org/conta-empresa/nome-projeto/commits/all

Comment: Então Ivan, eu não trabalho na mesma branch.
mas quando eu faço o merge parece que foi feito na mesma branch.

No seu exemplo foi mais completo, mas vou analisar

Comment: Se você desativar o [fast-foward](https://ariya.io/2013/09/fast-forward-git-merge), usando `-no-ff` no merge, vai ficar visualizável como você deseja, porém, você irá perder a linha de sincronismo.